# What does "wrd?" mean in a sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite

I have been struggling with storing blobs of data into a sqlite database. I queried the database directly from the terminal and saw that all of the values of the blob field are shown as "wrd?". What does this mean and is this normal when trying to view a blob field? Thank you.

[image: rightmost column is a blob field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT rowid, date, drawing, typeof(drawing) FROM drawings;
```

to see how sqlite is interpreting the column.

Also,

```
SELECT rowid, date, drawing, hex(drawing) FROM drawings;
```

may help you see the raw data.